# C# interactive skips breakpoints in code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-interactive

When troubleshooting a problem in my code I often use CSharp interactive to perform queries against some of my API's.

I have noticed, however, that when I put a breakpoint somewhere in my API code, when calling the containing method from the C# Interactive window, the breakpoint is not hit.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way that I could make C# interactive scripts hit the breakpoints in my API?

I have very little knowledge on how the VS debugger works, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your configuration is set 'Debug'. You certainly may have issues setting breakpoints, a method may have been inlined.

Comment: [The FM](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window) makes no bones about it: "The Interactive Window does not currently support any form of debugging".  That may change some day but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: That's too bad - it would have been really helpful for troubleshooting purposes.

Answer (score 10):

You actually *can* hit breakpoints in the interactive window. After loading the assembly you want to debug, you can either call `Debugger.Launch()` in the interactive window or use the menu option `Debug -> Attach to Process...` and choose `InteractiveHost.exe`. After that, breakpoints will be hit as normal.

Comment: Debugger.Launch didn't work for me. The interactive window blocked until I quit the debugger. However, attaching to the interactive host process worked like a charm. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you Attach to process and Breakpoints are skipped:
Tools > Options -> (left menu) Debugging section -> ( X )"Enable .NET Framework source stepping"